# docker-compose cli ignores current context

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I created a ssh context with `docker context create` command, the command like `docker ps -a` successfully executed on the remote machine
But when I run the `docker-compose up` command, the containers created in local machine, by running `docker context ls` I ensured that I am in the remote context

Why `docker-compose` ignores current context?

Comment: Can't reproduce, Docker 20.10.11, compose - 1.29.2. Did you use `docker context use <new_context_name>` to set the new context as default?

Comment: I am using `export DOCKER_CONTEXT=<new_context_name>`

Comment: Perhaps compose does not read that env var. Try with `docker context use`.

Comment: FYI, the env vars that docker-compose does read: https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/envvars/

Comment: @anemyte how can I use `docker context use` in safe way, I want to ensure that after running command, I switched to default context, may be I forgot to run `docker context use default`

Comment: I'm afraid there is no option to change it temporarily but there are alternative ways, which I mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To activate a context for `docker-compose`, use:

```sh
docker context use CONTEXT_NAME
```

But this will change the default context and it won't change back unless you run the command again with `default` as the context name. If it has to be a temporary switch of context, you can run `docker-compose` with `-c` flag:

```sh
docker-compose -c CONTEXT_NAME up
```

And there is also an alternative way without using context at all. `docker-compose` reads a number of [parameters](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/envvars/) from environment and `.env` file (in your current directory). You can add there `DOCKER_HOST` variable to change the host where `docker-compose` will execute your commands. For example:

```
DOCKER_HOST=ssh://example.com
```

or

```
DOCKER_HOST=tcp://10.0.42.11:2376
```

The list of supported environment variables is available [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/envvars/).